# How to use dapper with ASP.Net core Identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, dapper

I have a database and iam trying to use dapper with Core Identity to make queries to database. but i am stuck at this point. I am using a User from the interface of identityUser:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{

}
```

The with a making a custom user store for CRUD with dapper.

```
 public class UserStore : IUserStore<User>
{
    private readonly string connectionString;

    public UserStore(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        connectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("DBInfo:ConnectionString");
    }

    internal IDbConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        }
    }
    public Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
**// HOW TO I RETURN A USER WITH DAPPER HERE?**
    }

    public Task<IdentityResult> DeleteAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<User> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<string> GetUserIdAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<string> GetUserNameAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<IdentityResult> UpdateAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

thanks!

Comment: I'd advice you to read the documentation: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper Its basically an extension Library on `SqlConnection`/`IDbConnection`

Comment: What are you actually asking?  How to write creation logic against a database structure that we haven't seen?  This question is far too unclear and broad to answer.

Comment: 'public Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
**// HOW TO I RETURN A USER WITH DAPPER HERE?**
    }'

Comment: Did you have a look at [Identity.Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Identity.Dapper/ "Identity.Dapper")

Comment: I'd like to just point out that, whatever solution you'll implement, accordingly to this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1113), Asp.net Identity expects that the stores are following an unit of work pattern or you'll probably have subtle issues down the road

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Please take a look at a project that i recently uploaded on GitHub - https://github.com/giorgos07/Daarto It's exactly what you need.

Comment: Do you happen to have a version with Core 2.0? I've been trying to find an example somewhere but no luck. Trying to create a basic project with Dapper+AspNet Core Identity 2.0

Comment: @Bojan i have updated the project to ASP.NET Core 2.1

Comment: Great work! I think this should be a NuGet package.

Comment: @GiorgosManoltzas How can I extend Identity User class? Can you give a example?

Comment: @GiorgosManoltzas can you pl update your project to ASP.NET 6.0 ? Thanks again for such a helper to Dapper Community which microsoft ignores intentionally. Microsoft is doing its best to avoid Dapper

Comment: @vibs2006 thank you for your comment. Please take a look at the repo and NuGet. I added support for netstandard2.1 - net5.0 and net6.0