# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false in a non-auth methods after successful login in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, discord, authorization

I am new in asp.net core. I try to login with discord as 3rd party login service (like sign-in with facebook, google).

I can login successfully and have my user object, claims and I can enter a class which has an authorize attribute. Below you can see that UserIdentity is fine.

[image]

But let assume that user wants to go back to the login page. In this case, I have to redirect him to the index but I want to check whether the user is authenticated or not by using Identity and unfortunately, it is false and no claims etc. As I understand, it may be related with cookies or something similar. I also use different attribute for class (not authorize but AllowAnonymous) You can see below my Identity object

[image]

I am sharing my authentication code

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           
})
  .AddCookie(options =>
   {
      options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
      options.Cookie.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;
      options.SlidingExpiration = true;
      options.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents);
      options.AccessDeniedPath = "/auth/DiscordAuthFailed";

    })
     .AddJwtBearer(options =>
      {
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
           ValidateIssuer = false,
           ValidateAudience = false,
           ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
           ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Issuer"),
           ValidAudience = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Audience"),
           IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
               Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:EncryptionKey")))
        };
    })
     .AddOAuth("Discord",
         options =>
         {
           options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize";
           options.TokenEndpoint = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token";
           options.Scope.Add("identify");
           options.Scope.Add("email");
           options.Scope.Add("guilds.join");
           options.Scope.Add("guilds.members.read");

          options.CallbackPath = "/auth/oauthCallback"; 
          options.ClientId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Discord:ClientId");
          options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Discord:ClientSecret");
          options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://discord.com/api/users/@me";
                                            
          options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
          options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "username");
          options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
          options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.IsPersistent, "verified"); 

          options.AccessDeniedPath = "/auth/DiscordAuthFailed";
          options.Events = new OAuthEvents()
           {                         
             OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
              {
               var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
               context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
               request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
               request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);
                var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request,
                HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var user=(await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())).RootElement;

                context.RunClaimActions(user);

                }
          };
    });
```

services.AddTransient();

So my question is that, what is the best approach to access userIdentify object in any class/method after successfully login?

Comment: Hi, be sure `app.UseRouting`, `app.UseAuthentication`, `app.UseAuthorization`, and `app.UseEndpoints` must be called in the order shown in the preceding code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GetUserAsync` method that will check if a user has been logged in. You need to use the `UserManager` class that falls under the `AspNetCore.Identity` to a use the above method. In your case, it will look something like this:

You will first need to configure your `UserManager` class in `Startup.cs` by simply adding a parameter to the `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
{
 // your code
}
```

And then you can use it in your `Controller` method:

```
[Route("Account")]
public class AccountController: Controller
{

   private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

   public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
   {
     _userManager = userManager;
   }

   [Route("Login")]
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public IActionResult Login()
   {
      ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = User;
      var user =_userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result; 
      if(user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
        //redirect here
      }  

      return View();
   }
}
```

You need to update your `ConfigureServices` to include the Default Identity:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{  
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>  
        options.UseMySql(  
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));  
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)  
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();  
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but I get an exception "System.Exception: 'Could not resolve a service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[[Entities.DbClasses.User, Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' for the parameter 'userManager' of method 'Configure' on type 'Web.Startup'. InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Entities.DbClasses.User]' has been registered.'"   Do I have to add scope the UserManager class ?

Comment: @Unbalanced Yes, you need to register the identity in `Startup.cs`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483589/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager-w

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think it is a bit complex for me. Because I dont use mssql but mysql and I dont use EF but Dapper. So I dont have any dbContext to add AddEntitiyFrameworkStores etc.. Because whe I simply UserManager added, I get another error. https://i.imgur.com/PWAXid9.png

Comment: @Unbalanced Updated answer on how to include the default identity with Mysql DB

Comment: thank you for your reply. Probably your answer is right but I dont have DBConxtex. I am using Dapper. Well is it not possible to put these claims to the httpcontext directly ?

Comment: @Unbalanced You can take a look at this answer and hopefully it helps you out in setting up your identity as required: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140736/how-to-use-dapper-with-asp-net-core-identity

Comment: thank you soo much for your answers. I'll accept your message as the right answer. But I solved the problem without these things.. I'll write also about it

Answer (score 5):

After very long analyses, I found the problem.

I just changed  the DefaultAuthenticateScheme as CookieAuthenticationDefaults

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           
})
```

and called sign method in my login method.

```
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
 
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, result.Principal);
```

after successfully sign-in, I cna get HttpContext.User object in any action.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I need. I have tried to use `services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` but not work. No ideas why

Answer (score 2):

User.Identity.IsAuthenticate returns false in cases where you have multiple Authentication Scheme like JWT Authentication, Cookie Authentication running together.

To overcome this, you can Add Authentication Policy Schemes which chooses/filters out the Authentication Method to be used based on the incoming requests.

You can refer to this [blog](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Mar/29/Combining-Bearer-Token-and-Cookie-Auth-in-ASPNET) and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-multiple-authentication-schemes#code-try-7) by Microsoft which did the job for me.

Comment: Thank you for adding this comment, it was a needle in a haystack for me!